# Hazelcast and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm using spring boot 1.3.3 and Hazelcast
My build looks like:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
                <embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
                    <mode>service</mode>
                    <useStartStopDaemon>false</useStartStopDaemon>
                </embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

When the service is executed in Linux I see in log:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/cluster/impl/operations/WanReplicationOperation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

But I see hazelcast-all.jar in the fat jar
Any clue?

Comment: The stacktrace mentions Spring 4.2.4, but Spring Boot 1.3.3 uses Spring 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by spring-boot script.
Due to the fact that service stop didnt kill the process and it was still alive start failed to execute and throw such an exception in logs.
I still dont understand why it cant find specifically hazelcast classes and all the rest are ok